How can I align this "PushButton" to the right of the "Options" column and decrease the size of this specific column, without changing the others
How can I align this "PushButton" to the right of the "Options" column and reduce the size of this specific column, without changing the other columns.
I am using Python and QtDesign with PyQt6.
Below is the image:
MainWindow With QTableWidget
Below is the code:
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, uic, QtCore

def show_data(self, data, button_column_index=None):

    table = self.ui.tableWidget
    row_count = len(data)
    table.setRowCount(row_count)

    if data:

        for row, row_data in enumerate(data):

            row_data = list(row_data)
            row_data.append("")

            action_edit = QtGui.QAction("Edit", self)
            action_delete = QtGui.QAction("Delete", self)

            action_edit.triggered.connect(lambda: self.action_edit_triggered(table))
            action_delete.triggered.connect(lambda: self.action_delete_triggered(table))

            menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
            menu.addActions([action_edit, action_delete])

            option_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            option_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./user_interface/icons/menu.svg'))
            option_btn.setFixedWidth(24)
            option_btn.setFixedHeight(24)
            option_btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color:#f2f2f2; color:#f2f2f2; text-align:center; border-radius:12px;} QPushButton:hover{background-color:#d9d9d9;}")

            option_btn.setMenu(menu)

            for column, item in enumerate(row_data):
                if column == button_column_index:
                    table.setCellWidget(row, column, option_btn)
                else:
                    item_obj = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
                    table.setItem(row, column, item_obj)


The simplest solution is to create a QWidget as a container, set a layout (with contents margins set to 0), add the button to the layout with the alignment=Qt.AlignRight argument, and call setCellWidget() with the container above. Calling resizeColumnToContents() will do the rest. Note that in your code you're creating the button even though it may not be added (if button_column_index is None), which is quite ineffective.
